# How to run a function when tapping a Node in a Scene on Apple Watch?

Tags: scenekit, watchkit, apple-watch

I currently have a basic Scene using Scenekit and WKInterfaceSKScene, I have a SKSpriteNode called Player that i have positioned in the scene. I want to run a function when tapping on the player but
I am not able to understand how to do that or even return touch position on the Apple Watch.
Any help would be appreciated!